# Default value for optional type 'URL?'

Tags: ios, swift, forced-unwrapping, swift-optionals

I have an extension allowing me to download images to my `UITableView` from API.

```
extension UIImageView {

    func donwloadImage(from url: String) {
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data,response,error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error)
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.image = UIImage(data: data!)

            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

}
```

The app crashes if `imageUrl` is `nil`.

How do I wrap it using `??` so the `UIImageView` is just blank if there’s no image?

This is a data model and fetch data function

```
class Article: NSObject {

    var headline: String?
    var date: String?
    var imageUrl: String?
    var desc: String?
    var url: String?

} 

@objc func fetchArticles() {
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?pageSize=15&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=API_KEY")!)

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data,response,error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error)
                return
            }

            self.articles = [Article]()
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject]

                if let articlesFromJson = json["articles"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                    for articlesFromJson in articlesFromJson {
                        let article = Article()
                        if
                            let title = articlesFromJson["title"] as? String,
                            let publishedAt = articlesFromJson["publishedAt"] as? String,
                            let urlToImage = articlesFromJson["urlToImage"] as? String,
                            let description = articlesFromJson["description"] as? String,
                            let url = articlesFromJson["url"] as? String

                        {

                            article.headline = title
                            article.date = publishedAt
                            article.imageUrl = urlToImage
                            article.desc = description
                            article.url = url


                        }
                        self.articles?.append(article) // and so on...
```

Comment: You cannot assign a default value in `URL(string:` unless the string represents a **valid** URL to a placeholder image.

Comment: maybe i can provide some google 'empty image' url as a default value?

Comment: “The app crashes if `imageUrl` is `nil`.” ... Yet, in your code snippet, there is no `imageUrl`. Perhaps you can share a code snippet with `imageUrl`, showing us where’s it is crashing. But the typical pattern would be `imageView.image = nil; if let url = imageUrl { ... }`. Or, if you don’t want to set the `image` to `nil`, use some placeholder image that you have in your project.

Comment: Needless to say, the `nil`-coalescing operator, `??`, is not the right technique here. Use `if let x = y { ... }` or `guard let x = y else { ... }` patterns.

Comment: mr Rob i have added more code snippets, pls have a look

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a POD that downloads images asynchronously and always leaves an image of placeHolder, look at the following example that uses it:

```
import SDWebImage

imageView.sd_setImage (
   with: URL (string: "http://www.example.com/image.jpg"), 
   placeholderImage: UIImage (named: "placeholder.png") // define your default Image
)
```

Link para o POD: https://cocoapods.org/pods/SDWebImage

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your extension and added a placeholder param. So when you pass an invalid URL, the guard will handle that case and set the default image to imageview.

```
extension UIImageView {
   func donwloadImage(from url: String, placerholder: UIImage? = UIImage(named: "your-default-image")) {
        guard let imageURL = URL(string: url) else {
            self.image = placeholder
            return
        }
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: imageURL)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data,response,error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let imageData = data, let image = UIImage(data: imageData) else {
                self.image = placerholder // it up to you to set placeholder image in case of error
                //handle error
                return
            }
            self.image = image
        }
       }
       task.resume()
    }
}
```